# How to compare 2 TCP/IP stacks or implementations?

Tags: domain-name-system, tcpip, point-to-point-protocol

I have to recycle an old machine into a networking node for managing TCP/IP connections and PPP protocols ( basically a DSL connection ); I'm not asking for something more than this, all the tasks required are network-related tasks, no computing, just make it like a server.

I was wondering, how do professionals compare 2 different implementations of the TCP/IP stack while having to deal with 2 different OSs ? Like linux and bsd ?

My point is this, there is a unit of measure or a algorithm complexity, or something equivalent to take into account ?

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be hung off of a DSL connection, your TCP stack isn't going to be a bottleneck. If you were routing to a Gigabit or faster connection, then yes, perhaps it would be beneficial to look into this further.

Generally-speaking, BSDs have a more robust networking stack, but honestly that likely does not matter in your case.

I'd recommend you install [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) on the server (which is based on FreeBSD) and be done with it. It will likely do everything you need and much more.

Comment: +1 Until you get into the niche requirements, they're all close enough.

Comment: thanks for that name, I forgot about pfSense, but my question still is about why the 2 differs ? Why you can say that the BSD stack is better ?

Comment: Your question is like asking why an apple is different than an orange. The Linux kernel and the FreeBSD kernel are two completely different code bases.